# Ratio Test Intuitive Proof

Tags: calculus

For #2 of theory: If we let a.n be decreasing, then a.n+1 is less than a.n and since L is less than 1, when we multiply L by a.n we get a value approximately equal to a.n+1

Is this proof explanatory enough?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you want to do is compare to a geometric series.